# Find the difference between two strings

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

For example I have two strings:

`val string1 = "Nature is so beautiful"`

`val string2 = "Nature is very beautiful"`

so I want to print both the strings: "so" the previous string and "very" the edited string.
how can I achieve this, can anyone help me please?

I have been trying like this,

```
@Composable
    fun DifferenceText(oldText: String, currentText: String) {
        // Split both strings into lists of words
        val oldWords = oldText.split(" ")
        val currentWords = currentText.split(" ")

        // Compare each word in the old and current lists
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            for (i in oldWords.indices) {
                if (oldWords[i] != currentWords[i]) {
                    println(currentWords[i])
                    Text(text = currentWords[i])
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A good start is to look at the diff algorithm https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff

Comment: Did any of the answers helped you?

Answer (score 0):

```
    val string1 = "Nature is so beautiful"
    val string2 = "Nature is very beautiful"

    val listOfStringOne = string1.split(" ")
    val listOfStringTwo= string2.split(" ")

    var previousString = ""
    var editedString = ""

    for (i in listOfStringOne.indices){
        if (listOfStringOne[i] != listOfStringTwo[i]){  ->  compare two string and when match is not found then if condition execute and both of the string save in the declared variable. <br>
            previousString = listOfStringOne[i]  ->  String from first list (Previous String)  
            editedString = listOfStringTwo[i]  ->  String from second list (Edited String)
        }
    }
```

First of all we need to use a split function to make an list of the words in the sentence.

And we need to compare both of the list.

**If any word of second string is different from first string then we can save first list of string value in previous string & second list of string in edited string**.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like

```
val map = oldText.split(" ").map { it to 1 }.toMap().toMutableMap()
val newTextList = newText.split(" ")
val result = mutableListOf<String>()

newTextList.forEach {
    if (map.contains(it)) {
        map[it] = map[it]?.let { it + 1 } ?: 0
    } else {
        println(it) // will print "very"
        result.add(it)
    }
}

map.forEach {
    if (it.value == 1) {
        println(it.key) // will print "so"
        result.add(it)
    }
}

result.forEach {
    Text(text = it)
}
```

The solution above will let you to print all the words that are unique. Even if the numbers of words in sentences differ.

Assuming you will have only one word difference you can use `StringUtils.difference`

```
val a = StringUtils.difference(oldText, newText) // "very beautiful"
val b = StringUtils.difference(newText, oldText) // "so beautiful"
val c = StringUtils.difference(a.reversed(), b.reversed()).reversed() // "so"
val d = StringUtils.difference(b.reversed(), a.reversed()).reversed() // "very"
```